# Scala - error: illegal start of statement (no modifiers allowed here)

Tags: scala

Why do I get the error

```
error: illegal start of statement (no modifiers allowed here)
override def toString = {
^
```

when loading the following code (wrapped in a .scala file) from spark-shell (Spark version 2.2.0, Scala version 2.11.8)?

```
import org.apache.spark.util.StatCounter

class NAStatCounter extends Serializable
{
  val stats: StatCounter = new StatCounter()
  var missing: Long = 0

  def add(x: Double): NAStatCounter = {
    if (java.lang.Double.isNaN(x)) {
      missing += 1
    } else {
      stats.merge(x)
    }
    this
  }

  def merge(other: NAStatCounter): NAStatCounter = {
    stats.merge(other.stats)
    missing += other.missing
    this
  }

  override def toString = {
    "stats: " + stats.toString + " NaN: " + missing
  }
}

object NAStatCounter extends Serializable {
  def apply(x: Double) = new NAStatCounter().add(x)
}
```

It is an example code from a book and it looks weird I get this error...

Comment: is this the code verbatim? The error is a parsing error and I can't reproduce it.

Comment: this is weird. I've rewritten the code from scratch, a comparison tools says it's the same identical code, but now get the error

error: not found: type StatCounter (at line 5)

Comment: Ok, I had to move the opening curly brace on the same line of class definition, but still the "error: not found: type StatCounter" appears

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the error.

Comment: I just go inside spark-shell and type :load filename.scala

Comment: So none of you gets any error?

Comment: Using :paste with the above code works correctly... This is weird.

Answer (score 0):

toString method returns a String so just add return type to it.

```
override def toString: String = {
    "stats: " + stats.toString + " NaN: " + missing
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer but it was a parsing error. Using :paste with the above code works correctly